# How does it work the return in this "Prob" monad in the learnyouahaskell tutorial?

Tags: function, haskell, monads

I am having trouble understanding the return in the execution of flipThree in the following implementation:

```
import Data.Ratio  
import Data.List   
newtype Prob a = Prob { getProb :: [(a,Rational)] } deriving Show  


 -- Functor
instance Functor Prob where  
    fmap f (Prob xs) = Prob $ map (\(x,p) -> (f x,p)) xs  

-- Applicative
instance Applicative Prob where
  pure x = Prob [(x,1%1)]
  Prob [(x,r)] <*> something = fmap x something

-- Flatten works as join for Monads
flatten :: Prob (Prob a) -> Prob a  
flatten (Prob xs) = Prob $ concat $ map multAll xs  
    where multAll (Prob innerxs,p) = map (\(x,r) -> (x,p*r)) innerxs 

-- Monad
instance Monad Prob where  
    return x = Prob [(x,1%1)]  
    m >>= f = flatten (fmap f m)  
    fail _ = Prob []  

data Coin = Heads | Tails deriving (Show, Eq)  

coin :: Prob Coin  
coin = Prob [(Heads,1%2),(Tails,1%2)]  

loadedCoin :: Prob Coin  
loadedCoin = Prob [(Heads,1%10),(Tails,9%10)]  


flipThree :: Prob Bool
flipThree = do  
    a <- coin  
    b <- coin  
    c <- loadedCoin  
    return (all (==Tails) [a,b,c])
```

I can follow along the implementation of flipThree until I get to the following line:

```
return (all (==Tails) [a,b,c])
```

According to the result that I get, that is the following:

```
Prob {getProb = [(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(False,9 % 40),(False,1 % 40),(True,9 % 40)]}
```

I can see that it comes from having this before :

```
Prob {getProb = [([Heads,Heads,Heads],1 % 40),([Heads,Heads,Tails],9 % 40),([Heads,Tails,Heads],1 % 40),([Heads,Tails,Tails],9 % 40),([Tails,Heads,Heads],1 % 40),([Tails,Heads,Tails],9 % 40),([Tails,Tails,Heads],1 % 40),([Tails,Tails,Tails],9 % 40)]}
```

As long as I can see there is a little bit of the non-determinism of the list monad but i don't get to see why. My problem is understanding why all the possible outcomes of the Coin are being concatenated in the first parameter of the tuples as they are when we get this for example:

```
[([Heads,Heads,Heads],1 % 40),([Heads,Heads,Tails],9 % 40)]
```

Why is the monad list doing that when the Monad Prob is defined in a different way and in the return is supposed to return a Prob with the Rational 1 % 1 ?

Note:

The link to the tutorial is here:

http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#making-monads

I would really appreciate any help you can provide me as long as I've been stucked understanding all this the whole week.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return` does return a single value with probability `1%1`, but the result you're seeing is the result of `coin >>= (\ a -> coin >>= (\ b -> loadedCoin >>= (\ c -> return (all (== Tails) [a,b,c]))))`.  The result of `return` is being passed up through several layers of `>>=` first.  Does that help?

Comment: Isn't return the last layer of     >>= ?

Comment: It's the most deeply nested thing inside the `>>=`.  It's the _innermost_ expression.

Answer (score 1):

The Prob monad works just like the List monad except that it also keeps track of the current probability of all of the selections. When you finally `return` something, this current probability is multiplied by 1%1 to give the probability in the tuple.

We need the 1%1 at then end because the probability is set up as product of terms, and the final term in this product is 1%1.

Here is walkthrough of what happens with this monadic expression:

```
do a <- coin
   b <- coin
   return (a == b)
```

1. Select a value and probability for *a* - (*v1*, *p1*). This sets *a* to *v1* and the formula for the current probability formula *p1* * ... . We won't know what ... is until return at the end of the monadic expression is reached.
2. Select a value and probability for *b* - (*v2*, *p2*). This set *b* to *v2* and the current probability formula is extended to *p1* * *p2* * ...
3. Compute the boolean value *a == b*, and finish off the current probability computation by replacing ... with 1%1. The resulting Prob tuple will be (v1 == v2, p1 * p2 * 1).

Comment: But how is it possible for the return to concatenate all the possibilities if in the bind operator for the Prob monad there is no concat for the first parameter of the tuple but it applies the function f to the first parameter of the tuple. It's a function the one that concat all the "Heads" and "Tails" in the first parameter ? If so, where does this function come from?

Comment: That happens when the expression `[a, b, c]` is explicitly written.  That explicitly creates a list.

Comment: @user3457759 - `return` doesn't concatenate all the possibilities - it _generates_ a single possibility. Collecting all of the possibilities works just like the List monad machinery collects all the possibilities, like in `do a <- [1..3]; b <- [4..5]; return (a+b)` - so if you understand how the List monad works then you are halfway to understanding how the Prob monad works.

Comment: I do understand perfectly how the list monad works but i don't see (in code) how it is similar (because I don't know where in the code it is the concat of the first element of the tuples) to the Prob Monad where the bind operator is entirely associated to multiplying the probabilities and no mention to concat the first parameters of the tuple.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The list [a,b,c] would be a list of tuples right ? Associated as follows:

a = [(Heads, 1 % 2), (Tails, 1 % 2)]
b = [(Heads, 1 % 2), (Tails, 1 % 2)]
c = [(Heads, 1 % 10), (Tails, 9 % 10 )]

Comment: No, why would it?  `a`, `b`, and `c` are just `True` or `False`.  It's `[(Heads, 1 % 2), (Tails, 1 % 2)] >>= \ (a :: Bool) -> [(Heads, 1 % 2), (Tails, 1 % 2)] >>= \ (b :: Bool) -> [(Heads, 1 % 10), (Tails, 9 % 10)] >>= \ (c :: Bool) -> return (all (== Tails) [a, b, c])`

Comment: Oh but then a,b and c are True and False in a non-deterministic way ? I think I need more help with Monad than I thought

Comment: @LouisWasserman What I fail to see is in the bind operator of Prob Monad where is the non-deterministic part since the fmap is going to be applied to an element but I don't know where can I see that is going to be applied to all the possible values of the list since a,b,c can be Heads or Tails

Comment: There's no actual nondeterminism.  Work through on a piece of paper how the result of `[(Heads, 1 % 2), (Tails, 1 % 2)] >>= \ a -> return (a == Tails)` works, all the way from the beginning to the end, just by substituting in the definitions.

Comment: Oks I will, What else do you recommend me to improve my skills with Monads and execution of them ?